# Use Fragment with ViewPager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, swipeview

I am using View pager to create a swipe view effect

Now i want to implement different fragments on same activity fragments are different layout which are displayed according to the condition.

I am stuck on how to create `pagerAdapter` and how to create `fragment` class.

Code:

```
    public class mFragment extends Fragment{
    Context mContext;
public mFragment(Context context){
mContext = context;
}
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            return inflater.inflate(R.layout.main, ActivityScreen.mViewPager,false);
        }
    }



 public class mPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter
    {
        int i=-1;

        public mPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm)
        {
            super(fm);
            mViewPager.removeAllViews();
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount()
        {
            return data.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int pos) {
            return new mFragment(Context ctx);
        }
    }
```

Please help me on this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Override @instantiateItem method and return the fragments to update in the view

[use this link](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2011_08_01_archive.html)

will be helpful m i think

Answer (score 0):

in your FragmentActivity add an adapter for FragmentPagerAdapter then 
@Override Fragment getItem and add Fragments to it accourding to requirement

Comment: tried it but it gives error with the given code (code in question)